# Adding eventlistener to object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

I did a project for a to-do list and am trying to refactor it to be more object oriented. I'm having trouble figuring out how to make an object that adds an item to my list. After looking at many different examples, and answers to similar questions this is what I have now, but it doesn't work.

```
function Todo(){
  this.btn = document.getElementById('add');
  this.item = document.getElementById('item').value;
  this.list = document.getElementById('list');
  this.el = document.createElement('li');
  this.el.innerHTML = this.item;
  this.handler = function(){
    this.list = appendChild(el);
  };
  this.action = function(){
    this.btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){this.handler.bind(this);});
  };
}


var mine= new Todo();
mine.action();
```

I'm honestly not sure what I'm stuck on, but I'm fairly sure my eventListener itself in the this.action function is wrong.

HTML is as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Todo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>ToDo List</h1>
  <p>This is a todo list</p>
  <ul id='list'>

  </ul>
  <input id='item'></input>
  <button id='add'>Add Item</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide your HTML?

Comment: Updated with the html included. I don't think my HTML is the problem though. I suppose it could be.

Comment: You misspelled `getElementById` on the first line of Todo. Also, input is a [void element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element) so there's no need for a closing `</input>` tag.

Comment: Good catch didn't notice that, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the input information also. I don't write html as frequently and forget small things like that. I'm trying to focus on javascript and other server-side stuff at the time, but I need to keep up on the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a better way to write your code:

```
var TodoList = function() {
  this.addTodoItem = function() {
    var todoText = document.getElementById('item').value;
    var todoUl = document.getElementById('list');
    var todoLi = document.createElement('li');
    todoLi.innerHTML = todoText;
    todoUl.appendChild(todoLi);
  };
};

var todoList = new TodoList();

var bindEvents = function() {
  document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', todoList.addTodoItem);
};

var init = function() {
  bindEvents();
  // do any other initialization you want
};

window.onload = init;
```

First off, your `Todo` constructor. You were storing a bunch of DOM element objects as properties of some instance of the newly created Todo object (your `mine` variable).
There is no need for that. You just want to use these elements temporarialy. So, use local variables, as I did inside of `addTodoItem`.

Then we create an instance of the TodoList, which will handle any interaction with your todo list.

Also, it shouldn't be your constructor responsability to make the event bindings. Because of that, I've created the `init` function, which will be called after the full page load.
That is a pretty standard place for attatching events (considering you are not using jQuery). So, I got rid of your `action` function inside of the TodoList, and attached a function of the `todoList` object (which will be the object that will handle your todo list stuff) to handle the desired events.

Comment: Thank you! This is the kind of advice I was looking for. I'm just starting to try to move towards using objects and don't really understand all the concepts yet. This answer was very helpful.

Comment: Thanks again. The explanation for moving the event out of the object and into the init function is what I needed to hear, that makes things a lot more clear. And I know jquery would make this project a lot easier, but I'm know jquery and I'm trying to implement this in javascript to really get the hang of what jquery is abstracting out.

Comment: Yeah, I think you should really not use jQuery always, just as you did. I was just mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function(e){this.handler.bind(this);}
```

When this is called, `this` will be the DOM Element (the button) that was clicked on, which has no `handler` method.

Also there's a typo on this line: `this.btn = document.getElemenyById('add');`, it should be **getElementById(...)**.

Comment: I thought that using the .bind(this) fixed that. At least that was what someone else told me to do that I asked about this. How would I make this apply correctly in this situation?

Comment: no, `bind` creates a new function which will always have it's `this` set to whatever it was binded to. This however applies to the function returned by `myFunc.bind(...)`. The anonymous function used as callback for your event is still getting the DOMElement as `this`.

Answer (score 0):

I have done little changes to your code. See the following link:
http://jsfiddle.net/29ppxpgm/5/

```
function Todo(){
    this.btn = document.getElementById('add');
    this.item = document.getElementById('item');
    this.list = document.getElementById('list');
    this.handler = function(){
        var el = document.createElement('li');
        var txt = document.createTextNode(this.item.value);        
        el.appendChild(txt);
        this.list.appendChild(el);
    };
    this.action = function(){
        var that = this;
        this.btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){that.handler()}, false);
    };
```

}

var mine= new Todo();
   mine.action();

Comment: Thank you this is the way I was trying to write it and just missed a few concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do something like this?

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = input.value;
    ul.appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
<button>Add Item</button>
<ul></ul>
```

Why would you want to make this object-oriented?

Comment: This is what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm trying to just learn how to use objects in a basic context. But also this is just the very start of what I'm trying to accomplish with this. I figured if I couldn't get this basic part to work then the rest would probably be a little much.

Comment: Well, objects are simply containers of properties and methods. I don't see any reason to make this code object-oriented because it is a single operation and it has no properties.

Comment: I plan on it being more than a single operation and to add a lot from here. Once again I was just making sure I could figure out the basics of implementing this problem with an object to ensure I could use objects for what I have planned for the rest of the project.